# "Те, кто умеет" или "те, кто умеют"?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, согласование

Вышел спор с сестрой по поводу написания одного предложения: "Самые счастливые те, кто умеет ценить то, что имеет, кто видит радость в простых вещах и те, кто не предъявляет к жизни высокие требования". Я ей сказал, что, на мой взгляд, правильно было бы *умеют и имеют*. Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Aer♦, вопрос изменён Вами; где запятая после простых вещей? перед "и те, кто"?

Answer (score 2):

> Вышел спор с сестрой, по поводу написания одного предложения:
>
> *"Самые счастливые **те, кто умеет** ценить **то, что имеет**..."*
>
> Я ей сказал, что, на мой взгляд, правильно было бы - ***умеют и
>   имеют***.

.

Правильны оба варианта.

Вот что говорит И.Б. Голуб в "Стилистике русского языка" (М., 2010) о предложениях с местоимением ***кто*** в функции союзного слова в придаточной части сложноподчинённого предложения, которому в главной соответствует соотносительное слово:

> *Все, **кто пришли** на занятие, **разобрались** в этом сложном вопросе.*
>
> *Те, **кто знали** о лекции, **пришли** послушать.*
>
> В таких предложениях форма множественного числа сказуемого,
>   относящегося к местоимению ***кто***, "поддерживается"
>   соответствующими формами соотносительного слова и сказуемого в главной
>   части предложения. Правда, это не исключает вариантов, и в этих
>   предложениях можно было бы сказать: ***все, кто пришёл***… Такая
>   координация предпочтительна в книжных стилях...

Answer (score 2):

При подлежащем – относительном местоимении ***кто*** (в функции союзного слова в придаточном предложении) сказуемое может стоять как в форме ***единственного, так и в форме множественного числа***, например:

а)      Все, кто не потерял еще головы, были против (Сергеев-Ценский); ...Те, кто не успел к двери, кинулись в радостной панике к окнам (Макаренко);

б)      Тут эти люди, кто по неразумию своему малодушно положили оружие, узнали стыд... (А.Н. Толстой); В полку служат теперь те, кто десять лет назад были пионерами, бегали в школу, играли в снежки (Б. Полевой).

Форма множественного числа, возможная при условии, что в главном предложении соотносительное слово и сказуемое тоже стоят во множественном числе, подчеркивает множественность производителей действия. Ср. разные формы согласованиям одном и том же сложном предложении: Все, кто мог ехать, ехали сами собой; те, кто остановились, решали сами с собой, что им надо было делать (Л. Толстой).

См::Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.

СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ 
    М.: ЧеРо, 1999 [§187. Сказуемое при подлежащем-местоимении вопросительном, относительном, неопределенном, отрицательном](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_05)

Answer (score 1):

"Самые счастливые те, кто умеет ценить то, что имеет, кто видит радость в простых вещах и те, кто не предъявляет к жизни высокие требования"
Поскольку нужно отредактировать ВСЁ предложение, а не только его части, то в контексте однородных придаточных уместно было бы употребить   "те, кто умеЕт ценить то, что имеЕт, КТО ВИДИТ(!) радость в простых вещах и те, кто не предъявляЕт..."
 Потому что,  "в главном предложении соотносительное слово и сказуемое стоят во множественном числе" везде, кроме выделенного придаточного, и оно будет выпадать из "общей грамматической картины". И будет это выглядеть стилистически некрасиво.