# Кто и как "воспитывают" или "воспитывает"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Кто и как воспитывают талантливых учителей Германии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Однозначно: ***Кто и как воспитывает** талантливых учителей Германии?*

Сравнить: ***Какие педагоги и как воспитывают** талантливых учителей Германии?*

Варианты возможны только для **относительного** местоимения ***КАК***, эта тема рассматривалась на форуме:

**["Те, кто умеет" или "те, кто умеют"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429523/%D0%A2%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82/429526#429526)**